# Using Named Routes with MapSpaFallbackRoute

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, single-page-application

I am using named routes in my ASP.NET Core SPA like so:

```
[HttpGet("", Name = HomeControllerRouteName.GetIndex)]
public IActionResult Index() => this.View();
```

In my `Startup.cs` I use the `MapSpaFallbackRoute` method to fallback to the single page application to show 404 error pages. It currently uses the controller and action name to determine the fallback route like so:

```
application.UseMvc(
    routes =>
    {
        routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
            name: "spa-fallback",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
    });
```

I would like to do use named routes in my `Startup.cs` for consistency. How can this be achieved?

Comment: You are showing an example of a named route (the `MapSpaFallbackRoute`), so it is not clear what your question is.

Comment: You are mistaken. That is not a named route. It uses a controller and action name.

Comment: `MapSpaFallbackRoute` has a value for the (optional) `name` argument. That means it is a named route. Your first example is a named *attribute* route. Are you saying you want to setup a fallback attribute route?

Answer (score 0):

Example taken from: https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/973

Map SPA fallback route conditionally

```
// API Routes
       app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        // This route will never be mapped when route starts with api
        app.MapWhen(x => !x.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api"), builder =>
        {
            builder.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                    name: "spa-fallback",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
            });
        });
```